# How to add a pair to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, append

I created the following dictionary: `d = {}`

I add to it a new key and a couple as the corresponding `d['Key1'] = (1, 2)`

If I print the dictionary

```
{ 'Key1': (1, 2) }
```

How can I add another pair of integers to the following dictionary to the following key in order to have

```
{ 'Key1': (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)}
```

Is it possible to do it in Python? if yes How can I do it?

Can I also count the number of values that correspond to a specific key?

Comment: You cannot have three values to one key. You can however have a tuple with three tuples in it as your value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible but you need to use a container for your values.

For example you can use a list,also you can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method for assignment if your keys will have a multiple values, this is useful of you want to add another key with multiple values :

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('Key1',[]).append((1,2))
>>> d
{'Key1': [(1, 2)]}
>>> d['Key1'].append((1, 3))
>>> d
{'Key1': [(1, 2), (1, 3)]}
>>> d.setdefault('Key2',[]).append((4,2))
>>> d
{'Key2': [(4, 2)], 'Key1': [(1, 2), (1, 3)]}
```

> **setdefault(key[, default])**
>
> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

Comment: I wanted to use a dictionary because I have many keys not only just one. Is that possible even in lists?

Comment: @user1680944 yes its possible,you can use any type of python data structure or object as a dictionary values!

Answer (score 1):

That's only possible if you make the initial entry a list.

```
D['key'] = []
D['key'].append((1,2))
D['key'].append((3,4))

{'Key': [(1,2), (3,4)] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly; in other words, a `dict` can't hold multiple values associated with the same key. You would need to have a `dict` of `list`s.

If the set of keys isn't known in advance, you might want to use a `defaultdict`, which will automatically create a `list` (or whatever) each time you access a key which doesn't already exist in the dictionary.

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

To add elements, you would use

```
d['Key1'].append((1, 2))
```

instead of

```
d['Key1'] = (1, 2)
```

This lets you avoid writing special code to handle the first insertion with a given key.

Comment: I have a problem with collections, I get the following error: d = collections.defaultdict(list)
NameError: name 'collections' is not defined.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: You have to `import collections` first. (I figured that was implied.)